# What's the fastest way to screen capture to a GIF for demonstrations?

Tags: discussion

When posting an answer it's common to want to illustrate an idea using an animated diagram or screen capture. I have some screen capture software ([iShowU](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowu)) but it doesn't have and export to GIF option built in. I also know of a website for quickly creating animated GIFs from an image sequence ([gifmaker.me](http://gifmaker.me/)), but I have to crop in an image editor and export the frames first, so it's not very efficient.

**Are there any apps or web apps you guys recommend for preparing an animated GIF quickly from what's on the screen?**

*Attention: This post is not specific to one software title or website!*

I'm looking for something that will work on a Mac, but this conversation is intended to invite discussion of options for all OSes that Blender can run on (Mac/Linux/Windows).

Thanks!

Comment: Were you asking about a screen recording of your user and mouse gestures?  Were you asking about any series of screen captures?  Blender render of image sequences of jpegs or png files?

Comment: I just wanted to know how others make GIFs so quickly. Unfortunately a trigger-happy gandalf3 marked it as a duplicate so others probably won't find this question and benefit from it. It's not a duplicate btw, this is not about gfycat specifically. Anyway, it's solved. I found that .mov files made with iShowU can be converted to GIFs using this site: http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-gif and I also found that loading a series of  screen shots into PhotoShop and exporting as a GIF is easier than I thought: http://www.briandalessandro.com/blog/create-an-animated-gif-in-photoshop-cs5/

Comment: Yes.  Your post seems quite open to variety of solutions/techniques. I happen to use GIMP for GIF creation. It works satisfactorily.  I sometimes see imperfections which I have not investigated. Thanks.